# How do i implement dark mode using states and save the setting to my localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a darkmode in ReactJS. I tried looking up other answers in stackoverflow, but none os uses the same approach as i am using.

## What I am trying to do:

**=>** Build a dark/light mode web application, so when i click button it switches from dark mode to light mode to dark mode to light mode and so on..

## What is my approach:

**=>** I created a simple one page dummy header with few texts and heading. I adde a "switch" button , which when click will toggle between dark/light mode.

**=>** I have initiated my "state" with boolean, and added onClick button to my "Switch" button. Whenever we click the button, it calls a function called handlechange() which further updates out "state" using "this.setState" and changes our boolean value.

**=>** Based on our boolean values the "className" of our div is changing which render specific set of styles for dark and light mode which i have further defined in my CSS.

## What is working:

**=>** The button is working well, and i am able to switch between modes.

## What is the problem:

**=>** I am trying to store the boolean in my localstorage in the browser.

**=>** the reason is, even if the user refreshes the page, they stay on the same mode which they selected previously.

**=>** I have managed to store the boolean value in my localstorage in the variable name "toggle" and tried to console.log(toggle), and it DOES changes from false,true,false,true and so on, but when i replace my class name from

```
<div className={this.state.setClass ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
```

to

```
<div className={toggle ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
```

It simply does not work, means the button does not respond to the changes and stays on light mode, even if the toggle variable is changing from true,false,true,false.. so on(when i try to log).

What should be my approach for the problem, so that i can even store the value in localstorage and use the localstorage for className?

Thank you for reading patiently.
Help me out Please :)

My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./DarkMode.scss";

class DarkMode extends React.Component {
  state = {
    setClass: false
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      setClass: !this.state.setClass
    });
    
  };

  render() {
    localStorage.setItem("Mode", !this.state.setClass);
    let toggle = localStorage.getItem("Mode");
    console.log(toggle);
    return (
      <div className={this.state.setClass ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
        <nav>Toggle goes Here</nav>
        <main>
          <h1>Light Mode</h1>
          <h2>Toggle the switch to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Switch</button>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DarkMode;
```

Comment: You don't need to set the class in the state, you only need to set 'Mode' 
so when your component mounts you check for the mode in localStorage
const default mode = 'day';
`if(localStorage.mode && localStorage.mode !== "") {
    this.setState({...this.state, mode: localStorage.mode})
  }` else set default mode

Comment: woud you mind a little code for reference? it would be really helpful. You may edit my above code and edit

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul check this now https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815454/6544460 working as you are expecting. if you need any help let me know.

Comment: I have just added the code [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58816729/1452861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58816729/1452861)
Since you are will be storing only one string or boolean value in the localStorage you can simply do `localStorage.item = true` or your value.

You also need to check for mode in localStorage before setting it in your state.
and since your class is stored in the css file you don't need to carry it around in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse like this `let toggle = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode"));`

```
class DarkMode extends React.Component {
 state = {
    setClass: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode"))
  };

  handleChange = () => {

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode")) === true)
      this.setState({ setClass: false }, () => {
        localStorage.setItem("Mode", JSON.stringify(false));
      });
    else {
      this.setState({ setClass: true }, () => {
        localStorage.setItem("Mode", JSON.stringify(true));
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { setClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={setClass ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
        <nav>Toggle goes Here</nav>
        <main>
          <h1>Light Mode</h1>
          <h2>Toggle the switch to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Switch</button>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
    }
```

Comment: For some reason even after parsing, i am able to switch between mode, but when i refresh, it is always showing light-mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: initializing state to just    !JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Mode")) did the trick, we do not need if else in the handleChange function

Comment: The issue was probably because we were not initiating state with anything but empty value, it should have been initiated. with some saved boolean from localstorage.

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul check now it's working properly as i can see in my system.

Comment: Sure, thank you for your help! It is working when I initialized the state properly

Answer (score 1):

First of all - localStorage can hold only string values, so your flag will be converted to `'true'` of `'false'` - both are truthy. You need to serialise/deserialise your data:

```js
localStorage.setItem('app_data', JSON.stringify({ toggle }));
...
const { toggle } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_data'));
```

The second thing - it's better to perform side effects (such as reading/writing localStorage) in callback, not in render function:

```js
handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      setClass: !this.state.setClass
    });

    localStorage.setItem('app_data', JSON.stringify({ toggle: !this.state.setClass }));
  };

componentDidMount() {
  const { toggle } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_data'));

  this.setState({
    setClass: toggle
  });
}
```

Comment: I think it os not updating our state, i tried the above code and i am getting an error "cannot read property toggle of null"

Comment: I forgot to add fallback for first call: `const { toggle } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_data') || '{}')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import "./DarkMode.scss";

class DarkMode extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    darkMode: true
  };

componentDidMount() {
  if(localStorage.darkMode) {
    this.setState({...this.state, darkMode: localStorage.darkMode}) 
  }
}

handleChange = () => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, mode: !this.state.mode });
  localStorage.darkMode = this.state.darkMode;
 };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}>
        <nav>Toggle goes Here</nav>
        <main>
          <h1>Light Mode</h1>
          <h2>Toggle the switch to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Switch</button>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DarkMode;
```