# Contact label, placeholder & input text color is black in dark mode in react app

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am new to React.js, I have a Contact.jsx component in which there is a simple form. I have toggle button in header to toggle dark mode/light mode and in light mode(default) text is black but in dark mode it is still black which is not visible.

Contact.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const Contact = ({ darkMode }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  });

  const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await axios.post('', formData);
      setShowSuccessMessage(true);
      setFormData({ name: '', email: '', message: '' });
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error sending message. Please try again later.');
    }
  };

  const formStyles = {
    color: darkMode ? 'white' : 'black',
  };

  return (
    <div className='contact'>
      <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={formStyles}>
        <div className='formfield'>
          <TextField
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={formData.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            inputProps={{
              style: formStyles,
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='formfield'>
          <TextField
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            inputProps={{
              style: formStyles,
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='formfield'>
          <TextField
            label="Message"
            name="message"
            value={formData.message}
            onChange={handleChange}
            multiline
            rows={4}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            inputProps={{
              style: formStyles,
            }}
          />
        </div>
        {showSuccessMessage && (
          <div>
            Thank you for your submission, your message was sent successfully!
          </div>
        )}
        <Button
          variant='contained'
          type='submit'
          size='large'
          className='customButton'
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

[Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKycz.png)
[Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVCKU.png)

I tried to change it through adding class and removing on toggle but it still didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i implement dark mode using states and save the setting to my localstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815340/how-do-i-implement-dark-mode-using-states-and-save-the-setting-to-my-localstorag)